# Why doesn't "service cron start" work within the Docker file?

Tags: docker, service, cron

When I start the cron service within the running Docker container with

```
service cron start
```

it works. But the line

```
RUN service cron start
```

within the Dockerfile seems not to have an effect. Why?

### Alternatives

I thought about simply changing my `CMD` to something like `CMD ["startup.sh"]` which first runs `service cron start` and then `run.py` (a Python webserver). But I want the web server not to run as root and thus `service cron start` would fail.

Comment: Maybe this answer would apply here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27970447/249687

Comment: Here's a related question with two good answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135897/how-to-automatically-start-a-service-when-running-a-docker-container

Comment: I am interested in what is the best answer in this situation. Also interested in which solution did you pick for your app. I guess cron container is the good solution for this, is it?

Answer (score 12):

Each `RUN` command creates a temporary container on your build host using the resulting image from the prior step and the `RUN` arg as the container's command. A container only runs as long as the command you execute is active, so if it's a command that launches a background daemon like you've done, the container exits when the command returns, not when the background daemon exits.

The `RUN` command is used to build up your image which is the layered filesystem and various meta data that tells docker how to use that filesystem (environment variables, entrypoint and/or command to run by default, etc). It is very different from a `CMD` which tells docker what to run when that image is turned into a container. So for a process that you need to have running in the container, that needs to be part of your `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` since running processes from `RUN` are not part of a static filesystem image.

I'd also follow the advice of others and copy an already existing image with cron inside, no need to reinvent this wheel. You may want to use a tool like supervisord to run cron and your application together if you need to have multiple processes inside your container. Though when possible, you should work out how to break this into multiple containers that can be independently updated.

Answer (score 5):

When you execute command `service cron start` process cron will be detached from shell. But Docker works only while main process is alive.

You need move cron into `entrypoint`. A good example [here](https://github.com/renskiy/cron-docker-image)